# UITableView bounce bottom edge only

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, uitableview, uikit

Is it possible to bounce a `UITableView` on the bottom side, but not the top? If so, please show me code.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Instead of changing the `bounces` property, I added that to the `UIScrollViewDelgate` method:

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will prevent scrolling to top completely

Comment: It would be better to set `bounds` rather than `contentOffset` to avoid calling the delegate a second time, especially if there is more code in `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

Answer (score 8):

**For swift 4**

```
extension YourViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == tableView {
            let a = scrollView.contentOffset
            if a.y <= 0 {
                scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint.zero // this is to disable tableview bouncing at top.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

It should be possible by observing UITableview's contentOffset property.

```
[_tableView addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"contentOffset" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:NULL];
```

. . and preventing the offset from going negative.

Comment: UITableView is a sub-class of UIScrollView. . . this gives me an idea. . . observe content offset. . if it goes negative, lock back to zero.

Answer (score 4):

I have also encountered this problem and my solution is:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
 if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100) {
     scrollView.bounces = NO;
 }else{
     scrollView.bounces = YES;
 }
}
```

I use this code in my project and it work well.

Answer (score 2):

You could try using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods to detect dragging direction and adjust the `bounces` property appropriately?

Comment: Hi i tried observing and changed the tableview.bounces to NO accordingly when offset reaches negative but there is glitch when the tableview goes in negative. How did you avoid it , please share me your solution if it did'nt occur to you.

Answer (score 1):

### Swift

```swift
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

     //Check to make sure this only applies to tableview 
     //and not other scrollviews inside your View/ViewController
     if scrollView.superclass == UITableView.self {
     //bounce will only be true if contentOffset.y is higher than 100
     //I set 100 just to make SURE, but you can set >= 0 too
         scrollView.bounces = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 100
     }
        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In swift 2.2:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    } else {
        scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = YES;
    }
}
```

@Liron Berger 's solution will cause VerticalScrollIndicator still showing, just set `showsVerticalScrollIndicator` to `NO` can solve this problem