# enable bouncing for only one direction UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How would I go about allowing a `UITableView` to bounce when it reaches the bottom, but not the top. Essentially I'm adding a `UIImageView` as my `TableView's` section header, but currently if I pull up at the top there's an ugly space between my `UIImageView` and my `UINavigationBar`.

I look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166983/uitableview-bounce-bottom-edge-only) but I don't really understand the solution. Would somebody mind elaborating?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The question you link to has 2 different solutions. As the delegate of the table view you are already the scroll view delegate, so you could implement something like (this is the answer that isn't tagged as correct in the other question...):

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollView.bounces = (scrollView.contentOffset.y > 10);
}
```

Comment: huh, I get the following error: Invalid operands to binary expression ('CGPoint' (aka 'struct CGPoint') and 'int'). Do you know what this means?

Comment: Yep, it means I missed 2 characters. You can't compare a `CGPoint` to an `int`...

Comment: ah I see =) This solution works almost perfectly. If I accelerate very quickly upward, it flickers a little bit against the background. Is there a way to prevent that from happening?

Comment: 10 was an arbitrary value, you can make that bigger depending on how big the content of the scroll view is. You could also put the check in a different delegate method (like `scrollViewDidEndDragging:willDecelerate:`).

Comment: Got it. I'll play around with it. Thanks again.

Comment: Apologies for downvoting but this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17166983/uitableview-bounce-bottom-edge-only is better because in this implemenation the view still scrolls slightly at the top before changing the bounce property. Basically, there's no need to manipulate the bounce property

Comment: If you make check against larger number than 10 you will most probably not get flickering at the top. Upvote because this solution suits me more than @RoystonYinkore 's linked one since it doesn't introduce another point of `contentOffset` change for which I would have to account.

Comment: Oh well, apparently when you block bouncing it blocks content offset so I have to deal with it still :(

Answer (score 4):

The contentOffset is the distance between the origin of your frame (0, 0) and the origin of the first cell.

[image: iOS: The default coordinate system has its origin at the upper left of the drawing area, and positive values extend down and to the right from it. You cannot change the default orientation of a view’s coordinate system in iOS—that is, you cannot “flip” it.]

Initially, the contentOffset is zero. If you've scrolled past the top of the list (dragging finger downwards), then the contentOffset will be negative. If you've scrolled down the list (first cell is above the frame), then the contentOffset will be positive.

```
#pragma mark - UIScrollViewDelegate 
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    CGFloat maxOffset = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height);
    CGFloat originOffset = 0;
    // Don't scroll below the last cell.
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= maxOffset) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x, maxOffset);

    // Don't scroll above the first cell.
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= originOffset) {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
    }
}
```